# Update SQL records in Winforms App (language: C#)

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, sql-update

I am having trouble updating the records in my database using the textboxes and picture box. When I try to update, it gives me the error: Could not find a part of a path.

Below is the coding:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace CO6009DissertationV5
{
public partial class frmViewCatManagement : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = SQL2016; Initial Catalog = db; Persist Security Info=True;User ID = user_db; Password=#####");
    SqlCommand com;
    string imgLoc = "";


    public frmViewCatManagement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmViewCarManagement_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DataGridViewImageColumn dgvCarCat = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        //dgvCarCat.HeaderText = "Image";
        //dgvCarCat.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
        //dataGridView1.Col
    }

    // 
    //  Buttons
    //
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string imgPath = txtPath.Text;
            FileStream fs;
            fs = new FileStream(imgPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] picbyte = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(picbyte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
            fs.Close();
            con.Open();
            string qry = "UPDATE tbl_catManagement SET (catclass, carmake, cardescription, carimage) VALUES ('" + txtCatClass.Text + "', '" + txtCarMake.Text + "','" + txtCarDesc.Text + "', @img)";
            //catclass='" + txtCatClass + "', carmake='" + txtCarMake.Text + "', cardescription='" + txtCarDesc.Text + "', carimagePath'" + txtPath.Text + "', @img)";
            SqlParameter imgParameter = new SqlParameter();
            imgParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
            imgParameter.ParameterName = "img";
            imgParameter.Value = picbyte;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(imgParameter);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

    }

    private void btnFindData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string sqlQuery = "SELECT catname,catdescription,carimage FROM tbl_manageCat WHERE catid= '" + txtCatID.Text + "'";
        //cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
        //SqlDataReader DataRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //DataRead.Read();

        //if (DataRead.HasRows)
        //{
        //    txtCarClass.Text = DataRead[0].ToString();
        //    txtCarName.Text = DataRead[1].ToString();
        //    txtCatDesc.Text = DataRead[2].ToString();
        //    byte[] images = ((byte[])DataRead[1]);

        //    if (images == null)
        //    {
        //        picBoxCar.Image = null;
        //    }

        //    else
        //    {
        //        MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(images);
        //        picBoxCar.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
        //    }
        //}

        //else
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("This Data is not available");
        //}

        //connection.Close();

        //dataCarCategory.ColumnCount = 3;
        //dataCarCategory.Columns[0].Name = "catid";
        //dataCarCategory.Columns[1].Name = "catname";
        //dataCarCategory.Columns[2].Name = "catdescription";

        //DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        //Image image = Image.FromFile("Image Path");
        //img.Image = image;
        //dataCarCategory.Columns.Add(img);
        //img.HeaderText = "carimage";
        //img.Name = "img";
    }

    private void btnViewData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        //{
        //if (txtCatID.Text == "")
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Category ID");
        //    return;
        //}

        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT carimage FROM tbl_catManagement WHERE catid=" + txtCatID.Text, con);

        ////SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_catManagement catid= " + txtCatID.Text + "catclass= " + txtCarClass, con);
        //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //da.Fill(ds);

        //if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        //{
        //    //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].["carimage"]);

        //    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["carimage"]);
        //    picBoxCar2.Image = new Bitmap(ms);

        //    panel4.Visible = true;
        //    panel5.Visible = false;
        //}

        //else
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("Image not found");
        //}
        //}

        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        //}

        //finally
        //{
        //    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        //    {
        //        con.Close();
        //    }
        //}

        con.Open();
        string sqlQry = "SELECT catclass, carmake, cardescription, carimagePath, carimage FROM tbl_catManagement WHERE catid= '" + txtCatID.Text + "'";
        com = new SqlCommand(sqlQry, con);
        SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        sdr.Read();

        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            txtCatClass.Text = sdr[0].ToString();
            txtCarMake.Text = sdr[1].ToString();
            txtCarDesc.Text = sdr[2].ToString();
            txtPath.Text = sdr[3].ToString();
            byte[] img = (byte[])sdr[4];
            panel4.Visible = true;
            panel5.Visible = false;
            panel6.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;


            if (img == null)
            {
                picBoxCar2.Image = null;
            }

            else

            {
                MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(img);
                picBoxCar2.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This data is not available");
        }

        con.Close();
    }

    private void btnViewAllData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmDGVCatManagement frmdvgCM = new frmDGVCatManagement();
        frmdvgCM.Show();
    }

    private void btnFindCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel4.Visible = false;
        panel5.Visible = true;
        panel2.Visible = false;
        panel6.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "png files(*.png)|*.png|jpg files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files(*.*)|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtPath.Text = ofd.FileName;
            picBoxCar2.Image = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
        }
    }
}
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which line in the code gives error? Can you share the sample path value for which it is giving error /

Comment: it does not give an error on the line. But when I try to click on the UPdate Button, it gives the error message: Could not find a part of a path.

Comment: You are seeing message because you have used  try catch block and when exception occurs it goes to catch block and messagebox the exception message. You need either remove the try catch or debug the code and see from which line the exception occurs and goes to the catch block. As Sujit mentioned in the answer looks like the file path you are using in the code is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

"Could not find part of a path" means that file location is incorrect? Can you verify that file is present in that location? Sometimes when you refer the file only via filename, it might give this issue?

It's advisable that you always use FULL PATH when you are getting any path error so for your case, try to add a path like "C:\myPics\mypic.jpg" in your below line.
string imgPath = txtPath.Text;